# Get from parent with closest() to a specific child

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get specific children within a parent to change there classes. I am quite new to HTML and jQuery so pardon if there are weird things in it.
More specifically  i want to let all the classes with fa fa-star-o change to fa-star.

I am trying something like this: 
$(this).closest('all-star-wrapper').find('fa-star-o').stop(true,true).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="users">
                            <p>
                                <span class="rater">users</span>
                                <span class="all-star-wrapper">
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o left-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o right-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o left-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o right-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o left-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o right-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o left-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o right-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o left-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="star-wrapper">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star-o right-star"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

The jQuery:

<script>
    (function($){
    $('.fa').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
                       // $(this).parent().parent().child('fa-star-o').prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o');
                        $(this).closest('all-star-wrapper').find('fa-star-o').stop(true,true).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');//this is what i am trying
           },

        // Handles the mouseout
        function() {

            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star');
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('fa-star-o');
        })})(jQuery);</script>
```

The Styling:

```
.ratings {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.ratings .all-star-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.ratings .star-wrapper {
    width: 8px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}

.ratings .star-wrapper .fa {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #45b4d9;
}

.ratings .star-wrapper .fa.left-star {
    left: 0;
}

.ratings .star-wrapper .fa.right-star {
    right: 1px;
}

/* line 277, ../scss/_common.scss */
.ratings p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* line 281, ../scss/_common.scss */
.ratings div {
  clear: both;
}
/* line 285, ../scss/_common.scss */
.ratings .rater {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;

}
/* line 289, ../scss/_common.scss */
.ratings .fa {
  color: #45b4d9;
  font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual aim as the code is "a little confusing" and seems to be doing lots of extra things not needed in the example? :) A JSFiddle with your styling would be nice too :)

Comment: yeah sorry, i didn't clean it up i want to be able to let all the classes with fa-star-o change to fa-star but for that i need to get out to the parent and acces it as a child or so i think it is

Comment: Without styling those empty `spans` will not render anything useful... Can you at least provide the styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have periods(for class) eg `('fa-star-o')` should be `('.fa-star-o')` before selectors in your code

`$(this).closest('.all-star-wrapper').find('.fa-star-o').stop(true,true).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('.fa-star-o').addClass('.fa-star');`

Comment: It is because they are not full classes the full class would be .fa fa-star-o

Comment: @Lúthien: That would not be a “full class”, but an element that has/belongs to _both_ classes. And as such, that needs periods before _both_ class names, and no space in between: `.fa.fa-star-o` would select an element that has both the class `fa` and `fa-star-o`. Without the period, `fa-star-o` as selector would select an element with the _tag name_ `fa-star-o` (which of course doesn’t exist in HTML), and `.fa .fa-star-o` with a space in between would look for an element with class `fa-star-o` that is a descendant of an element with class `fa`.

Comment: dude just to clear up your basics there is nothing like full class and half class .. there are just 2 different class assigned to span elements .@CBroe explained it